# How can I get "tmux choose-tree" to highlight in a monochrome terminal?

Tags: tmux

I'm using tmux 2.9-rc (built from source) on Ubuntu 18.04 in an xterm window.

I normally run xterm with color disabled (`xterm -cm`). It can display text in bold and reverse video, but not in color.

When I run `tmux choose-tree -w` in a window with color enabled, the top half of the screen shows a list of windows with the current line highlighted with black text on a yellow background (normal text is black on white). I can easily navigate the list and type Enter to select a window.

With color disabled, the highlighting is invisible, which makes navigation difficult.

Is there a way to configure tmux so it will visibly highlight the line for the selected window? Either bold or reverse-video would be ok.

Note that `setw -g window-status-current-style bold` highlights the name of the current window in the status line.

I'm looking for something like `windowlist -b` in GNU screen. (I recently switched from GNU screen to tmux, and this is the only feature I'm having trouble with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing mode-style to reverse.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I added `setw -g mode-style reverse` to my `$HOME/.tmux.conf`.